# Installing Nvidia binary drivers with .X509 certs

Tags: nvidia, certificates

The Nvidia README states that.X509 certs need to be used for kernel module signing.
    1) Where do I get the certs, and
2) How do I get the kernel to trust and accept the certs?

Here is the link for the NVidia readme file   [NVidia README, chapter 4](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/319.32/README/installdriver.html)

Comment: Is there any reason why you're installing directly from the Nvidia's binary?

Comment: I am using 3 GTX 970's in a graphical intensive system. I would like to install additional kernel modules to reduce system load. The load average starts at 3, then slowly climbs to 5, then crashes when the levels go above 7. I know this is quite high for a linux box. I believe this can be easier to achieve than using the drivers availible from the repo's